# How to close iframe from third partner after timeout in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a script of a payment gateway:

```
<script src="https://assets.pagar.me/checkout/1.1.0/checkout.js"></script>
```

When the user click to pay an item I call the next code. It open a modal dialog into a iframe to fill data from credit card to pay the item.
My app will work in kiosk mode and I´d like to close the iframe after a timeout.

I have tried:

```
setTimeout(function(){
     function closeWin()   // Tested Code
     {
     var someIframe=document.
       getElementById('easyXDM_PagarMeCheckout_default6958_provider')
       .contentWindow.document;
    }
    closeWin()
 },30000)
```

but it doesn't work. Here is How I call the function of the script to execute a payment:

**UPADATE:**
I achieve a way to find the iframe using:

```
var ifr=$('#easyXDM_PagarMeCheckout_default6958_provider', parent.document);
```

I am trying now:

```
ifr.remove()
```

but no success.

```
var checkout = new PagarMeCheckout.Checkout({
        encryption_key: 'ek_test_f9cws0bU9700VqWE4UDuBlKLbvAAA',
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        },
        close: function() {
          console.log('The modal has been closed.');
        }
      });

      var params = {
                      "amount":128000,
                      "customerData":"true",
                      "paymentMethods":"boleto,credit_card",
                      "postbackUrl":"requestb.in/1234",
                      "items": [
                        {
                          id: '1',
                          title: 'Bola de futebol',
                          unit_price: 12000,
                          quantity: 1,
                          tangible: true
                        },
                        {
                          id: 'a123',
                          title: 'Caderno do Goku',
                          unit_price: 3200,
                          quantity: 3,
                          tangible: true
                        }
                      ]
                    };
      var ck=checkout.open(params);
```

Here is a copy of the iframe:

```
<iframe name="easyXDM_PagarMeCheckout_default3498_provider" id="easyXDM_PagarMeCheckout_default3498_provider" src="https://assets.pagar.me/checkout/1.1.0/modal.html?xdm_e=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&amp;xdm_c=default3498&amp;xdm_p=1" frameborder="0" style="z-index: 9999; background: transparent; border: 0px none transparent; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
#document
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
      <title>Checkout</title>
      <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:600,500,400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300,300italic,400,400italic,600,600italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/pagarme-ui.css?version=5">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/card.css?version=5">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/icons.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/mobile.css" media="only screen and (max-width: 600px)">
      <script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script>
         (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
         m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
         })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      </script>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery.bez.min.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery.color.min.js"></script>
      <!--[if lte IE 7]>
      <script src="json.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
      <script src="raven.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         Raven.config('https://4a6f66d610de4a0ab3d822d95075cff2@sentry.pagar.me/3').install();

      </script>
      <script src="animations/default.js"></script>
      <script src="card.js"></script>
      <script src="easyXDM.js"></script>
      <script src="modal.js"></script>
      <!--[if lte IE 9]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/pagarme-ui-ie8.css" />
      <script src="animations/ie.js"></script>
      <script src="modal-ie8.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
      <!--[if lte IE 7]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/pagarme-ui-ie7.css" />
      <![endif]-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/pagarme-ui-ie.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="pagarme-checkout-ui" style="opacity: 1;">
         <div id="pagarme-checkout-header">
            <a href="#" class="pagarme-modal-box-previous-step" id="pagarme-checkout-back-link" style="visibility: hidden;"><span class="icon-pg-checkout-back"></span><span class="no-mobile"> Voltar</span></a>
            <ul class="pagarme-checkout-step-indicator mobile show">
               <li href="#" class="pagarme-checkout-choose-payment-method-bullet step-indicator-bullet active" style="margin-top: -100px;">•</li>
               <li href="#" class="pagarme-checkout-step-buyer-information-bullet step-indicator-bullet" style="margin-top: -100px;">•</li>
               <li href="#" class="pagarme-checkout-customer-address-information-bullet step-indicator-bullet" style="margin-top: 0px;">•</li>
               <li href="#" class="pagarme-checkout-credit-card-information-bullet step-indicator-bullet" style="margin-top: 0px;">•</li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" id="pagarme-checkout-close-link"><i class="icon-pg-checkout-close"></i></a>
         </div>
         <div id="pagarme-modal-loading" style="display: none;">
            <div class="spinner"></div>
         </div>
         <div id="pagarme-modal-box" style="top: 0px; opacity: 1;">
            <p id="pagarme-checkout-step-title"><span class="no-mobile">Qual a </span><span class="mobile-capitalized">forma</span> de pagamento<span class="no-mobile">?</span></p>
            <p id="pagarme-checkout-amount-information">Total a pagar <span class="brand-color" style="color: rgb(26, 110, 225);">R$<span class="checkout-amount">1.280,00</span></span></p>
            <ul class="pagarme-checkout-step-indicator no-mobile show">
               <li href="#" class="pagarme-checkout-choose-payment-method-bullet step-indicator-bullet active" style="margin-top: -100px;">•</li>
               <li href="#" class="pagarme-checkout-step-buyer-information-bullet step-indicator-bullet" style="margin-top: -100px;">•</li>
               <li href="#" class="pagarme-checkout-customer-address-information-bullet step-indicator-bullet" style="margin-top: -100px;">•</li>
               <li href="#" class="pagarme-checkout-credit-card-information-bullet step-indicator-bullet" style="margin-top: -100px;">•</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="pagarme-checkout-step hidden" id="pagarme-modal-box-step-boleto-installment-information" style="opacity: 0; display: none;">
            </div>
            <div class="pagarme-checkout-step hidden" id="pagarme-modal-box-step-boleto-only" style="opacity: 0; display: none;">
               <div id="pagarme-checkout-boleto-button" class="brand-background-color darker-hover choose-method-button-container arrow" style="background-color: rgb(26, 110, 225);">
                  <button>
                     Boleto bancário <span id="boleto-discount" class="payment-discount"></span>
                     <div id="boleto-helper-text" class="payment-method-helper-text boleto-helper-text"></div>
                  </button>
                  <span class="button-indicator icon-pg-checkout-continue"></span>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pagarme-checkout-step next hidden" id="pagarme-modal-box-step-buyer-information" style="opacity: 0; display: none; left: 100px;">
               <div class="error-message" style="display: none">
                  <span></span>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group pagarme-checkout-input-container">
                  <input id="pagarme-modal-box-buyer-name" name="pagarme-buyer-name" placeholder="Nome" type="text">
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-success-mark icon-pg-checkout-success"></span>
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-error-mark icon-pg-checkout-error"></span>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group pagarme-checkout-input-container">
                  <input id="pagarme-modal-box-buyer-email" name="pagarme-buyer-email" placeholder="Email" type="email">
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-success-mark icon-pg-checkout-success"></span>
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-error-mark icon-pg-checkout-error"></span>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group pagarme-checkout-input-container">
                  <input id="pagarme-modal-box-buyer-document-number" name="pagarme-buyer-document-number" placeholder="CPF/CNPJ" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="14" autocomplete="off">
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-success-mark icon-pg-checkout-success"></span>
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-error-mark icon-pg-checkout-error"></span>
               </div>
               <div id="pagarme-checkout-ddd-field-container" class="pagarme-checkout-input-container">
                  <input id="pagarme-modal-box-buyer-ddd" name="pagarme-buyer-ddd" placeholder="DDD" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="2" autocomplete="off">
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-success-mark icon-pg-checkout-success"></span>
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-error-mark icon-pg-checkout-error"></span>
               </div>
               <div id="pagarme-checkout-phone-number-field-container" class="pagarme-checkout-input-container">
                  <input id="pagarme-modal-box-buyer-number" name="pagarme-buyer-number" placeholder="Número" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="10" autocomplete="off">
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-success-mark icon-pg-checkout-success"></span>
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-error-mark icon-pg-checkout-error"></span>
               </div>
               <button class="form-group pagarme-modal-box-next-step brand-background-color" style="background-color: rgb(26, 110, 225);">Continuar <span class="icon-pg-checkout-continue"></span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="pagarme-checkout-step" id="pagarme-modal-box-step-choose-method" style="opacity: 1; left: 0px; display: block;">
               <div id="pagarme-checkout-card-button" class="brand-background-color darker-hover choose-method-button-container arrow" style="background-color: rgb(26, 110, 225);">
                  <button id="pagarme-credit-card-payment-method" class="brand-border-color" style="border-bottom-color: rgb(49, 125, 228);">
                     Cartão de crédito <span id="credit-card-discount" class="payment-discount"></span><br>
                     <div id="credit-card-helper-text" class="payment-method-helper-text"></div>
                  </button>
                  <span class="button-indicator icon-pg-checkout-continue"></span>
               </div>
               <div id="pagarme-checkout-boleto-button" class="brand-background-color darker-hover choose-method-button-container arrow" style="background-color: rgb(26, 110, 225);">
                  <button>
                     Boleto bancário <span id="boleto-discount" class="payment-discount"></span>
                     <div id="boleto-helper-text" class="payment-method-helper-text boleto-helper-text"></div>
                  </button>
                  <span class="button-indicator icon-pg-checkout-continue"></span>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pagarme-checkout-step next hidden" id="pagarme-modal-box-step-credit-card-information" style="opacity: 0; display: none; left: 100px;">
               <div id="pagarme-checkout-card-container">
                  <div class="card">
                     <div class="front">
                        <p class="general expiration-label field">Valido ate</p>
                        <p class="general number field">•••• •••• •••• ••••</p>
                        <p class="general expiration field">MM/AA</p>
                        <p class="general name field">Nome completo</p>
                        <p class="amex cvv field">••••</p>
                        <p class="amex expiration-label field">Valido ate</p>
                        <p class="amex number field">•••• •••• •••• ••••</p>
                        <p class="amex expiration field">MM/AA</p>
                        <p class="amex name field">Nome completo</p>
                     </div>
                     <div class="back">
                        <p class="cvv field">•••</p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="error-message" style="display: none">
                  <span></span>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group pagarme-checkout-input-container brand-display">
                  <input id="pagarme-modal-box-credit-card-number" name="pagarme-credit-card-number" placeholder="Número" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="19" autocomplete="off">
                  <span class="brand-icon"></span>
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-success-mark icon-pg-checkout-success"></span>
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-error-mark icon-pg-checkout-error"></span>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group pagarme-checkout-input-container">
                  <input id="pagarme-modal-box-credit-card-name" name="pagarme-credit-card-name" placeholder="Nome (igual no cartão)" type="text" autocomplete="off">
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-success-mark icon-pg-checkout-success"></span>
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-error-mark icon-pg-checkout-error"></span>
               </div>
               <div id="pagarme-checkout-credit-card-expiration-container" class="form-group pagarme-checkout-input-container">
                  <input id="pagarme-modal-box-credit-card-expiration" name="pagarme-credit-card-expiration" placeholder="Validade" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="5" autocomplete="off">
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-success-mark icon-pg-checkout-success"></span>
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-error-mark icon-pg-checkout-error"></span>
               </div>
               <div id="pagarme-checkout-credit-card-cvv-container" class="form-group pagarme-checkout-input-container">
                  <input id="pagarme-modal-box-credit-card-cvv" name="pagarme-credit-card-cvv" placeholder="CVV" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="3" autocomplete="off">
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-success-mark icon-pg-checkout-success"></span>
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-error-mark icon-pg-checkout-error"></span>
               </div>
               <div tabindex="-1" class="pretty-select-wrap">
                  <div id="pagarme-checkout-installments-container" class="form-group pagarme-checkout-input-container">
                     <div class="pretty-select-container">
                        <span class="placeholder installments-value">Parcelas</span>
                        <img src="images/select-icon.png">
                        <select id="pagarme-modal-box-installments" name="pagarme-installments" placeholder="Parcelas" style="display: none;"></select>
                     </div>
                     <span class="pagarme-checkout-success-mark icon-pg-checkout-success"></span>
                     <span class="pagarme-checkout-error-mark icon-pg-checkout-error"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="pretty-select-select-container hidden">
                     <div class="select-arrow"> </div>
                     <ul class="select-options"></ul>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <button class="form-group pagarme-modal-box-next-step brand-background-color" style="background-color: rgb(26, 110, 225);">Pagar (R$<span class="checkout-amount">1.280,00</span>)<span class="icon-pg-checkout-continue"></span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="pagarme-checkout-step next hidden" id="pagarme-modal-box-step-customer-address-information" style="opacity: 0; display: none; left: 100px;">
               <div class="error-message" style="display: none">
                  <span></span>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group pagarme-checkout-input-container">
                  <input id="pagarme-modal-box-customer-address-zipcode" name="pagarme-customer-address-zipcode" placeholder="CEP" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="9" autocomplete="off">
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-success-mark icon-pg-checkout-success"></span>
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-error-mark icon-pg-checkout-error"></span>
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-loading"><img src="images/loading.gif"></span>
               </div>
               <div id="pagarme-checkout-address-street-field-container" class="form-group pagarme-checkout-input-container">
                  <input id="pagarme-modal-box-customer-address-street" name="pagarme-customer-address-street" placeholder="Rua" type="text">
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-success-mark icon-pg-checkout-success"></span>
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-error-mark icon-pg-checkout-error"></span>
               </div>
               <div id="pagarme-checkout-address-number-field-container" class="form-group pagarme-checkout-input-container">
                  <input id="pagarme-modal-box-customer-address-number" name="pagarme-customer-address-number" placeholder="Núm." type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" autocomplete="off">
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-success-mark icon-pg-checkout-success"></span>
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-error-mark icon-pg-checkout-error"></span>
               </div>
               <div id="pagarme-checkout-address-complementary-field-container" class="form-group pagarme-checkout-input-container">
                  <input id="pagarme-modal-box-customer-address-complementary" name="pagarme-customer-address-complementary" placeholder="Complemento" type="text">
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-success-mark icon-pg-checkout-success"></span>
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-error-mark icon-pg-checkout-error"></span>
               </div>
               <div id="pagarme-checkout-address-neighborhood-field-container" class="form-group pagarme-checkout-input-container">
                  <input id="pagarme-modal-box-customer-address-neighborhood" name="pagarme-customer-address-neighborhood" placeholder="Bairro" type="text">
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-success-mark icon-pg-checkout-success"></span>
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-error-mark icon-pg-checkout-error"></span>
               </div>
               <div id="pagarme-checkout-address-city-field-container" class="form-group pagarme-checkout-input-container">
                  <input id="pagarme-modal-box-customer-address-city" name="pagarme-customer-address-city" placeholder="Cidade" type="text">
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-success-mark icon-pg-checkout-success"></span>
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-error-mark icon-pg-checkout-error"></span>
               </div>
               <div id="pagarme-checkout-address-state-field-container" class="form-group pagarme-checkout-input-container">
                  <input id="pagarme-modal-box-customer-address-state" name="pagarme-customer-address-state" placeholder="UF" type="text" maxlength="2" autocomplete="off">
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-success-mark icon-pg-checkout-success"></span>
                  <span class="pagarme-checkout-error-mark icon-pg-checkout-error"></span>
               </div>
               <button class="form-group pagarme-modal-box-next-step brand-background-color" style="background-color: rgb(26, 110, 225);">Continuar <span class="icon-pg-checkout-continue"></span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="pagarme-checkout-step hidden next" id="pagarme-checkout-error-container" style="opacity: 0; display: none; left: 100px;">
               <div id="pagarme-checkout-error-header">
                  Transação não autorizada
               </div>
               <div id="pagarme-checkout-error-body"></div>
               <a id="pagarme-checkout-error-back-button" href="">Preencher dados de cartão novamente</a>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
         </div>
         <div id="pagarme-checkout-footer">
            <div id="footer-container">
               <p id="pagarme-checkout-secure-connection"><span class="icon-pg-checkout-locker"></span> Você está em uma conexão segura</p>
               <p id="pagarme-checkout-pagarme-brand"><span class="no-mobile">tecnologia </span><a href="https://pagar.me" target="_blank"><span class="icon-pg-checkout-pagarme-logo"></span></a></p>
               <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script>
         (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
         })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

Comment: You cannot close an iframe, because it is an html element. You only can remove it from the DOM tree.

Comment: Or you can set it to `display:none`

Comment: Yes, but in my code  the iframe is never found. The line var someIframe=document.
       getElementById('easyXDM_PagarMeCheckout_default6958_provider') returns null

Comment: Of course it returns null, because your iframe element that you have shown has `id="easyXDM_PagarMeCheckout_default3498_provider"`

Comment: @CBroe Thank you I fix it. But I can´t remove it or hide it. Any suggestion? It seems the script generate a new id and name dinamically each time.

Comment: Well then select it via any of the countless other means possible ... for example by its position in the DOM.